# How to use leverage caching on a website where ONLY FEW pages need to updated frequently?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser, mod-expires

I wrote the expiry of png,jpg,html,css,js and all in the .htaccess as 1 month.
But few of the html are being updated frequently. How can i manage that ?
Also, if i change my .htaccess, will the browser download contents again or still load it from the cache ?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

This is the code I wrote in .htaccess.

Now if I make any changes, will the browser still load from the cache because the expiry is 1month, or will it load the new content ?

In my case it loads the new content ONLY WHEN I HARD REFRESH A PAGE. But a user doesn't know that he needs to do that. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you set the expiry header based on the modification date of the source files. This can be done by:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 month"
```

You could also achieve this using:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpe?g|html?|css|js)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: But this would keep the content in browser cache for 1 month right ? How will the updated page get loaded without hard refreshing if I make a change after 2 days ?

Comment: @ShayanAnwar "The difference in effect is subtle. If `M` is used, all current copies of the document in all caches will expire at the same time, which can be good for something like a weekly notice that's always found at the same URL. If `A` is used, the date of expiration is different for each client; this can be good for image files that don't change very often."

Comment: Look at the code i added above in my question, would your code instruct the browser to load the updated content instead of cache even if the cache is yet to expire without hard refreshing ?

Comment: @ShayanAnwar Yes. But if your browser currently has cached the files with previous `access..` syntax, then you'll need to clear cache first.

Comment: How does e commerce websites work with leverage caching? Like they get their content updated every hour still i don't have to clear my cache or refresh the page. In my case a normal user never knows whether he is accessing the old content or the new one until i ask him to clear the cache. But that's not the proper way :-) right !

Comment: They already set their cache to use `modification` values from the beginning.

Comment: @ShayanAnwar I think you misunderstood my previous comment. My `Expiration` module config above will force the browser to redownload the content if it was changed on the server. Whereas, your code (because of `access plus..` syntax, won't do so. Since your browser has already loaded the files with `access..` syntax first, I instructed you to clear the cache first. After that, the `modification...` syntax will work just as you intend.